# deploy SSIS Package to different environments (Dev, Test, Prod)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

i have developed SSIS Packages with VS2013 and deployed them on MS SQL 2012 runing on SQL Agent Job.
Now i want to deploy them to different environments without changing variables, Parameters everytime before deploying... 
What i need is: for example if i want to deploy to Test, so i must just choose Setting for test and click deploy(like ASP.NET), is that possible?
Another question: For Raw File Destination, i can only write a hard value! how can i manage it when i deploy? (see picture)

[image]

Comment: Are you running package or project deployment model?

Comment: yes i use deployment model

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using 2012, you have [Environment Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213230(v=sql.110).aspx) available to use.  For the initial package, you will need a hardcoded value, but when the package is ran in the specific environment, the environment variable will take over.

Comment: You can even have multiple Environments and just reference the appropriate one in the job.  Of course, having different folders / different servers and an environment each is a much more acceptable choice.